# Installation with pictorial representation - stand alone install

Tags: boot, partitioning, hard-drive

I have searched the internet for this answer and cannot find one that suits my situation - close but still not close enough.

I have a laptop that has a 500GB SSD and a 2TB HDD.
I've heard numerous install setups from var on HDD to all on the SSD???

Ok, here's what I'd like to see the pictorial representation during the "Installation Type" screen during the install I'd like for someone to break it down for an idiot like me (I'm waaay more visual in my learning).

Which drive and how much for *(it appears maybe something like this):*

> - /dev/sda  (SDA noting the 500GB drive SSD)
>
>   - /dev/sda1 ext4 /boot     425GB
>   - /dev/sda2 ext4 /usr       43GB
>   - /dev/sda3 swap            32GB
> - /dev/sdb  (SDB noting the 2TB drive HDD)
>
>   - /dev/sdb1 ext4 /home     1.75TB
>   - /dev/sdb2 /var            250GB

Would the above partitioning work/work well?

and if one of those in the list needs to be removed or renamed please do so - this is just to start.

Oh, btw, I have 16GB of ram.
I will NOT be installing Windows, but will need some space for VirtualBox to install Windows for Office and 'maybe' some gaming - I prefer not to dual boot.  I may nix Windows altogether...hate Windows.
Ok, rant over - thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: `/dev/sda` and `/dev/sdb` are the two disks. Which one is the SSD and which one is the HDD depends on the BIOS/EFI and cannot be changed by the OS or the installer. (Therefore the question as written is meaningless; you *cannot choose* which drive is `/dev/sda`.) It may even happen that they change meanings from one boot to the next; that's why you should never ever call them `/dev/sda` and `/dev/sdb` in `fstab` but use UUIDs instead. Now what I would do is install the OS on the SSD and use the HDD as a data drive, with the goal of maximizing responsiveness and confort.

Comment: Ok, maybe I mispoke about the sda and sdb.  It does not matter to me - I am using the SSD as primary for OS and the HDD for data/files, etc...

Comment: I prefer to read text instead on looking at pictures. But I can give a few hints of what you need to include in the question in order to get a good answer. (1) Do you want to use full disk encryption, and if yes, do you want to encrypt both the OS disk and the data disk, or only the OS disk? (2) Does the computer boot in BIOS (aka "legacy") mode or in EFI mode? (3) Do you plan to use use LVM or not? (4) Do you want a separate `/home` partition (which may make future version upgrades easier)? Most importantly: have you tried to boot the computer from an installation medium into a live session?

Comment: Thank you for your response.  1) not necessarily...  2)  UEFI mode for the laptop  3)  Not sure what LVM is but have seen it mentioned for later updates/upgrades   4) prefer separate /home partition I think...  I have not yet but plan on trying this week to install it on current laptop into VirtualBox to see how well it runs prior to clean install for hardware compatibilities - just trying to prep for when I do.

Comment: I would suggest that the first thing to do is to boot the computer from an installation medium into a live session and see whether everything works all right - video, sound, networking. The live session is very very close to what an installed system can do; if the live session works satisfactorily then you can be quite confident that the installed system will work.

Comment: Agreed, but I still would like a setup for when I do get into a 'clean' install of Ubuntu.

Comment: Would my edit above from yesterday be a good install method?

Comment: `/boot` is not needed as a separate filesystem on UEFI systems; and it should be small. I suppose that you meant `/` (the root filesystem), not `/boot`. And on UEFI you need `/boot/efi` for the bootloader (about 250 MiB, formatted FAT32). AFAIK modern Linux systems do not even support `/usr` as a separate filesystem. Honestly, I don't understand why anybody would want `/usr` and `/var` as separate filesystems except in very exceptional situations. I would make `/` and `/boot/efi` on the SSD, and `/home` on the HDD and that's it.

Answer (score 0):

I like closure so since I asked for a graphic I have included one.
[Install Ubuntu graphic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5YXTG.png)